# Turn A String Of Clothes Sizes "xs,s,m,l,xl" into some you can select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I have an Items Model and a Categories Model. When creating a Shirt category you can create all the sizes you expect a Shirt category to have.

At the moment the sizes are a string "XS, S, M, L, XL, XLL"

**How do i make it so its something you can select?**

**For instance when you create an Yellow Shirt item you might only have XS and L available.**

See below

```
2.2.1 :002 > c = Category.last
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Category id: 14, name: "Shirt", ancestry: nil, created_at: "2015-09-01 10:09:32", updated_at: "2015-09-01 10:09:32", sizes: "XS, S, M, L, XL, XLL">
2.2.1 :003 > c
 => #<Category id: 14, name: "Shirt", ancestry: nil, created_at: "2015-09-01 10:09:32", updated_at: "2015-09-01 10:09:32", sizes: "XS, S, M, L, XL, XLL">
2.2.1 :004 > c.sizes
 => "XS, S, M, L, XL, XLL"
```

Categories Controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category,   only: [:show]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy, :index, :edit]

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    @tags = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).tag_counts_on(:tags)
    if params[:tag]
      @items = Item.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @items = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :sizes, :parent_id)
    end
    
    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
    end
    
end
```

Categories Form

```
<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for(@category) do |f| %>
          <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :name %>
          <%= f.input :sizes %>
          <%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Incase you need the Items view

```
<h1>Create New item</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for @item, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :image%>
            <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true, :prompt => "Select One Category" %>
            <%= f.input :tag_list %>
            <%= f.input :title%>
            <%= f.input :price %>
            <%= f.input :description %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create new item", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Migration for turning sizes into an array.

```
class AddSizesToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :categories, :sizes, :string, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

Comment: Make a sizes model and use either collection_check_boxes or have a multiple select.

Comment: I think a good first step would be to structure the sizes differently. I would store them as an array, so you can iterate through them, and select from them. If you're on PostgreSQL and Rails 4 then you can create an array column in the database, or if not you can serialize the attribute as an array.

Comment: One of my Rails friends said to use an enumerator? Do you think thats a good idea?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Thanks for your reply David. Just 1 thing. When turning it into an array. Does the migration file look like the one above? I left an example.

Comment: Make it :text, not :string, but otherwise yes that's it. I think I might add "null: false" as well. That would be to create a new column of course, which you couldn't do if you already had a size column on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the enum type for this. In your Category model you could define all possible values:

```
enum sizes: [:xs, :s, :m, :l, :xl, :xll]
```

In the database enum types are stored as integers, so you could then use an array of integers, so basically in your migration you would only have to change it to:

```
add_column :categories, :sizes, :integer, array: true, default: []
```

In your form you can then get the values from this enum type like this:

```
<%= f.input :sizes, collection: Category.sizes.keys, as: :check_boxes, input_html: { multiple: true } %>
```

In your categories_controller you also need to allow the array for the sizes parameter like this:

```
def category_params
  params.require(:category).permit(:name, :parent_id, sizes: [])
end
```

Comment: Hi Egon thanks for your reply. Just to make sure. Do you mean for the enum sizes add all the clothes sizes possible? Including sizes for shoes, shirts, and jeans.

Comment: Yes that would be needed. Maybe you could also add some clothing_type to your category and then only display specific values of the enum type based on this selection. But I don't know if this is needed in your specific scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah a clothing type would be needed otherwise the list will be huge. How would you ago about this? The only way i know how to do that would be to get rid of Categories model, then i would create a Sub Class of Item. Lets say Shirt Class which is a sub class of Item and in the Shirt class put enum sizes: [:xs, :s, :m, :l, :xl, :xll]. Repeat for all 20 type of clothing items hahaha.

Comment: Yea it's not so easy. I would probably have like different size_types, like "numeric", "international", "shoes", or something. Then you could also keep your one category model but really don't know enough about this topic to specify it exactly.

Comment: Nah i think your original will work. Theres only like 30 different size types. Its all good its only in the backend. Users wont be able to make Categories only admin so thats fine. Egon thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should create a array/enumrator for this and this can be accessible anywhere in app. So create a `initialize.rb` file under `config/initializers`.

```
## config/initializers/initialize.rb

CATEGORIES = [["XS","XS"],["S","S"],["M","M"],["L","L"],["XL","XL"],["XLL","XLL"]]
```

In your categories form change:
    <%= f.input :sizes %>

to

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :sizes, CATEGORIES%>
```

When tou submit form and selected `XS, L, XLL`, You will get params `params[:category][:sizes]` like ["XS", "L", "XLL"]

Change that in string format and save to db. You are done

Comment: Sweet jesus thats awesome! I will try it out!